# Как реализовать вызов компонента переменной на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mvc, node-modules

Всем доброго дня. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: подключил к React набор иконок через npm, и пытаюсь подключить его к проекту таким образом, чтобы из другого файла можно было прописав там свойство, переменная оттуда попадала как вызов компонента в файле прикрепленного фрагмента, поскольку имя компонента - название иконки.

Фрагмент (сам механизм присвоения иконки):

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import * as Icon from 'react-feather';
import SideMenuDropDown from './SideMenuDropDown';

export interface Props {
  link: any;
}

const TopSectionItem: FC<Props> = props => {
  const { link } = props;
  return (
    <div className="sidemenu-item dropdown">
      <a className="sidemenu-link" href={link.url} target={link.target}>
        <span className="icon-circle sidemenu-icon">
          {/*<i data-feather={link.icon} />*/}
          <Icon.Grid />
          {link.img && <img src={link.img} />}
        </span>
      </a>
      <SideMenuDropDown link={link} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopSectionItem;
```

```js
 data.NavTree = append(data.NavTree, &dtos.NavLink{
  Text:     "Текст",
  Id:       "textcomponent",
  SubTitle: "Подтекст.",
  //Icon:     "icon icon-textcomponent",
  Icon:     "Grid",
  Url:      setting.AppSubUrl + "/text",
  Children: textChildNavs,
 })
```

Соответственно вместо:

```html
<Icon.Grid />
```

надо прописать:

```html
<Icon.{link.icon} />
```

, но так невозможно. Можно ли каким либо образом сделать это менее костыльно, но без вмешательства в модуль node и в проект в целом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих экспериментов, сделал это таким образом: 
компонент IconsCollection - перечисление иконок:

```js
import * as Icon from 'react-feather';

const IconsCollection = {
  Grid: Icon.Grid,
  Hash: Icon.Hash,
  Bell: Icon.Bell,
  PlusSquare: Icon.PlusSquare,
  PlusCircle: Icon.PlusCircle,
  Plus: Icon.Plus,
  Shield: Icon.Shield,
  Settings: Icon.Settings,
  AlertOctagon: Icon.AlertOctagon
};

export default IconsCollection;
```

Затем написал компонент CallIcon:

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as Icon from "react-feather";
import IconsCollection from "./IconsCollection";

const CallIcon = props => {
  const HtmlCode = IconsCollection[props.icon];
  return (
    <HtmlCode size={Icon[props.icon].defaultProps.size} color={Icon[props.icon].defaultProps.color} />
  );
};

export default CallIcon;
```

И собственно в самом шаблоне это выглядит так:

```js
...

import CallIcon from './CallIcon';

...

<i className="fa fa-fw icon-custom">
    <CallIcon icon={link.icon} />
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно изменить скобки с `{}` на `[]` и убрать точку:

```
<Icon[link.icon] />
```

Comment: К сожалению webpack не воспринимает такое: 

[Webpack] ERROR in /home/msdnna/go/src/github.com/msdnna/ceres/public/app/core/components/sidemenu/TopSectionItem.tsx
[Webpack] ./public/app/core/components/sidemenu/TopSectionItem.tsx
[Webpack] [tsl] ERROR in /home/msdnna/go/src/github.com/msdnna/ceres/public/app/core/components/sidemenu/TopSectionItem.tsx(16,16)
[Webpack]       TS1003: Identifier expected.

Comment: @MistressDenna что такое Icon (я полагал что это объект)? и link.icon (я полагал что это строка)?

Comment: вот фрагмент собственно модуля.

type Icon = ComponentType<Props>;
export const Activity: Icon;
export const Airplay: Icon;